# Indexing with xindy \index{Alf|see {Alfred}}

Tags: xindy

When I use `\index{Alf|see {Alfred}}` I get the warning :

```
unknown cross-reference-class `see '! (ignored)
```

I dont want to use seealso;

Comment: Have you tried using it without the space (`\index{Alf|see{Alfref}}`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to note that `xindy` does search for its keywords and a group, meaning that it wants something like `see{Quack}` or `seealso{Quack}`. The faulty piece is the space in your code. You should use `\index{Alf|see{Alfred}}` instead.